# Regex php match string in prefix

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like : "aa 123xx123123.." or "aa12332432423..".
I want to find "123xx123123" and "12332432423". 
How can I put "aa" and "aa " in [] to match these like :
`/[aa,aa ]([\dx]{10,}).*/`

Comment: So you are looking for the `aa` prefix with or without a subsequent space? Just adding a `?` to make the space optional is sufficient: `/aa ?([\dx]{10,}).*/` That's a literal space, but if it could be any whitespace character (tab or newline), use `\s` as in `aa\s?`

Answer (score 0):

```
([\dx]{10,})
```

Try this.ou need not use match.Use search or find.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dK1xR4/6